# How do I configure Vim so that the color is different according to the first line, and the other lines wrap automatically?

Tags: vimrc

For some context, I'm talking about Git commits specifically. The Linux server that I use for work changes the color of the first line starting from column 53 (since 52 is the recommend commit title length) and for the body after column 70 the words wrap to the next line automatically.

How do I configure Vim to do this?

Comment: What you want is the default behavior if you enable syntax highlighting: `syntax on`.

Comment: Did you found a solution to your problem? How can we help you further?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `gitcommit` file type by adding a `gitcommit.vim` file into: `~/vimfiles/after/ftplugin`.

To change the body width to 50 you could add to the file:

```
setlocal textwidth=50
```

The first line warning is probably a specific colorization using a regular expression of the kind `\%>52v.`

Answer (score 1):

The column 70 wrapping can be set with

```
setlocal textwidth=70
```

as @VivianDeSmedt recommended. You can highlight columns 53 and greater on line 1 only using

```
call matchadd('Error', '\%1l\%>52v')
```

Note that "Error" can be any highlighting color group.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear whether you want to enable this behavior on your machine or change it. Since Vivian already explained how to override filetype settings, I'm going to talk about the other things.

The syntax highlighting and `textwidth` are set in two files called `gitcommit.vim`. One is located in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax`, the other one in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin`. These files come with Vim.

To set the filetype for the current buffer, write `set filetype=gitcommit`.

To have automatic filetype detection, put `:filetype plugin on` in your `vimrc`.

As always, refer to `:help` for the options mentioned above.

It's also possible to define new filetypes or define aliases. I once did this to apply git syntax highlighting to svn commit messages (not perfect but better than nothing).